# max price for grouped product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

I have a use case where I want to use grouped product

On the category/catalog page it shows the price as "starting from" and it shows the lowest price simple product. I actually want it to show the sum of the all of the attached products.

[image: category page]

I have a default qty of 1 in each item

[image: product setup page]

Firstly I would have expected M2 to show a price including both when the default qty equals 1, but apparently it doesn't - ill submit that as a improvement request and see if others agree.

So doing some searching on a solution I found this on [SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124882/group-price-for-product) which shows that tier pricing can manage the price for grouped product - I tried this, it has no impact on the price at all.

I then found this on [SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32364/how-to-get-min-max-regular-price-for-a-grouped-product-in-list-phtml) which shows a change to the code for Magento1.

Has anyone got a solution for this? or can that Magento1 solution be adapted to Magento2?